# ROOT without C++

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am going to be doing data analysis this summer using ROOT. But I don't have any background in C++. This question may be opinion-based but I need help. Is it possible to use ROOT without knowledge of C++?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the blurb I just read: "Thanks to the built in CINT C++ interpreter the command language, the
scripting, or macro, language and the programming language are all
C++." So it might be worth brushing up a little.

Comment: You can always use [PyROOT](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot) or [rootpy](http://www.rootpy.org/) for the lightweight parts of your heavy number crunching with ROOT. Nevertheless, off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.nevis.columbia.edu/~seligman/root-class/RootClass2012.pdf

Maybe this will help.

Can't hurt to read up a bit on the ol' C++ though.

What programming languages do you have experience with?

Comment: I have a little experience with java. I have been doing some ROOT tutorials, it doesn't seem so bad. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'd read up on pointers. Java puts a lot of that stuff behind the scenes, so the coder doesn't have to manage as much directly. 
Also memory management. 

Here are some more potential resources : 

[Moving from Java to C++](http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html)
and


[Brown CS123 Java to cpp](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs123/docs/java_to_cpp.shtml)

Answer (score 4):

If you know python you can try pyROOT. I actually prefer pyROOT over the C++ version.

It is the same thing, the same classes and methods. More info on the offitial ROOT web.